# How do I reuse this code instead of copying and pasting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I want to create and sync events from my calendar to a spreadsheet and viceversa.

The thing is I have 3 sheets inside my spreadsheet that I want to sync with a different calendar each.
So far I've made this:

```
function eventosDatos() {

  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calId");

  for (i = 3; i <= hoja.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var fecha = hoja.getRange(i, 8).getValue();

    if (fecha > 0) {
      var nombre = hoja.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var id = hoja.getRange(i, 11).getValue();

      if (id != 0) {
        var ulte = hoja.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
        var man = hoja.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
        var ide = cal.getEventById(id);
        var idf = ide.getAllDayStartDate();
        var idn = ide.getTitle();
        var ultev = ide.getLastUpdated();

        if ((ulte.valueOf() > ultev.valueOf()) && man == false) {
          ide.setAllDayDate(fecha);
          ide.setTitle(nombre);
          hoja.getRange(i, 9).setValue(ide.getLastUpdated());
          hoja.getRange(i, 10).setValue(true);
        }
        else if (ulte.valueOf() < ultev.valueOf()) {
          hoja.getRange(i, 8).setValue(idf);
          hoja.getRange(i, 3).setValue(idn);
          hoja.getRange(i, 9).setValue(ultev);
          hoja.getRange(i, 10).setValue(false);
        }
      }
      else {
        var nid = cal.createAllDayEvent(nombre, fecha).getId();
        var nultev = cal.getEventById(nid).getLastUpdated();
        hoja.getRange(i, 9).setValue(nultev);
        hoja.getRange(i, 11).setValue(nid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It accomplishes what i want but now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to reuse it instead of having to copy and paste it.

I thought about redeclaring variables like this:

```
...
     if (hoja.getSheetName()=="example 1"){
        cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendar for example 1");
      }
      else if (hoja.getSheetName()=="example 2"){
        cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendar for example 2");
      }
...
```

But then it wouldn't be a loop that checks and updates all 3 sheets one after the other without me running the code again. It would just check the sheet that's active and ignore the rest until I go to another sheet.

And I want to add a button in the menu aswell. But I do know how to do that.

My guess (I really don't know a lot about programming) is I'm looking for a way to make a function that checks and updates a calendar and a sheet, and another that assigns the right calendar Id and sheet for it look for going through all 3 sheets. And bind the latter one to a single button in the menu.

Any help is appreciated!

Sorry for any bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i undertood well, you can reutilizate code and receive parameters, for example

```
function firstEjecution() {
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var callId = hoja.getSheetName(); // You could change the sheet name as Calendar Id
  eventosDatos(calId,hoja);
}


function eventosDatos(calId,hoja) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);

  for (i = 3; i <= hoja.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var fecha = hoja.getRange(i, 8).getValue();

    if (fecha > 0) {
      var nombre = hoja.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var id = hoja.getRange(i, 11).getValue();

      if (id != 0) {
        var ulte = hoja.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
        var man = hoja.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
        var ide = cal.getEventById(id);
        var idf = ide.getAllDayStartDate();
        var idn = ide.getTitle();
        var ultev = ide.getLastUpdated();

        if ((ulte.valueOf() > ultev.valueOf()) && man == false) {
          ide.setAllDayDate(fecha);
          ide.setTitle(nombre);
          hoja.getRange(i, 9).setValue(ide.getLastUpdated());
          hoja.getRange(i, 10).setValue(true);
        }
        else if (ulte.valueOf() < ultev.valueOf()) {
          hoja.getRange(i, 8).setValue(idf);
          hoja.getRange(i, 3).setValue(idn);
          hoja.getRange(i, 9).setValue(ultev);
          hoja.getRange(i, 10).setValue(false);
        }
      }
      else {
        var nid = cal.createAllDayEvent(nombre, fecha).getId();
        var nultev = cal.getEventById(nid).getLastUpdated();
        hoja.getRange(i, 9).setValue(nultev);
        hoja.getRange(i, 11).setValue(nid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
          .addItem('Update animal', 'updateAnimal')
          .addItem('Update vegetable', 'updateVegetable')
          .addItem('Update mineral', 'updateMineral')
          .addItem('Update everything', 'updateAll')
          .addToUi();
    }

function updateAll() {
  updateAnimal();
  updateVegetable();
  updateMineral();
}
    
    function updateAnimal() {
      // does the sheet with animal stuff exist
      // does the calendar with animal stuff exist
      // call the code and pass in the animal stuff ids
    }
    
    function updateVegetable() {
      // does the sheet with vegetable stuff exist
      // does the calendar with vegetable stuff exist
      // call the code and pass in the vegetable stuff ids
    }
    
    function updateMineral() {
      // does the sheet with mineral stuff exist
      // does the calendar with mineral stuff exist
      // call the code and pass in the mineral stuff ids
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Wouldn't I be copying nad pasting the same code 3 times if i do this? I'm trying to avoid doing that so the code isn't as messy. Reading the description of the different update functions I think I get an idea of how I'd like to approach the problem: is it possible to pass information from one function to another? If so, how would i go about doing that? Do I create variables that store information and call them inside another function?

Comment: The code in your script editor is used by all sheets in a spreadsheet. If you are talking about multiple spreadsheets you would have to use something like a library. I have never done that.